# How to use a js datapicker with meteor blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to use this data picker https://github.com/richsilv/Pikaday/ in my meteor app.

After clicking in my input-field it should show this data picker. It works only one time, afterwards I get an error and I belive an infinite loop:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

and a lot of console.log messages from:

```
 console.log(this.getMoment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

What am I doing wrong and how to use this datapicker properly?

**html**

```
{{#each showDates}}
 <li>
  <input class="datapicker" type="text" value={{date}} id="data{{_id}}" />
 </li>
{{each}}
```

**js**

```
'click .datapicker': function(e) {          
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var picker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById(e.target.id),
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            onSelect: function() {
                console.log(this.getMoment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Edit: Maybe an important information: I need to click two times in input field to see this data picker. Then, I have to kill my browser process or to restart my meteor because of this error / infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not targeting the right id, shouldn't this:

```
field: document.getElementById(e.target.id),
```

be this?

```
field: document.getElementById(`data${e.target.id}`),
```

Comment: With `field: document.getElementById('data${e.target.id}'),` I get "Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null".  I belive I am targeting the right id, because with `console.log("ID:"+e.target.id);` I get: "ID:dataFL294nSfcJwqbf8fz" in the browser console.

Comment: Try to change your js to this:

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    'click .datapicker': function(e) {
        var picker = new Pikaday({
            field: document.getElementById(e.target.id),
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            onSelect: function() {
                console.log(this.getMoment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            }
        });
    },
});

Comment: It seems Meteor doesn't like this format / syntax. I can't wrap an Template-event with JQuery. I belive even if this would work it wouldn't solve my issue with infinite loop. I belive I use this datapicker on wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the picker (or other stuff you need to initialize) in

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function{
    //fires when the template is rendered
    //initialize whatever here. here is a pickadate example

    $('.elementClass').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: true,
        min: new Date(),
        closeOnSelect: true,
        onSet: function(context) {
             var selected = moment(context.select).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            //do something with selected
        },
        onClose: function() {
            //BONUS: this will prevent a bug/issue 
            //when you go to another tab or page and come back 
            //it fires the pickadate that was closed again.
            //this might be a bug in materializeCSS only
            $(document.activeElement).blur(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello. I am getting this error: _Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function_ . I tried to wrap your code with  `$(document).ready(function()` but it doesn't help.

Comment: @ProgrammingNovice first of all compare my onSet() with yours